# Google Sheets Query Match/Return data

Tags: google-sheets

Need to return data based on matching two columns from different sheets. Help appreciated

={"Video Views";ARRAYFORMULA(INDEX('Sheet1'!K2:K, MATCH('Sheet1'!Z2:Z,'Sheet2'!E2:E,0)))}

These are two exports that need matched by link, and return column k "video views" [Exports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4YMW.png)

Comment: share a sample sheet and it will be easier to answer

Comment: Index doesn't work in most array formulas. You might have  to create a table and then use Vlookup.

Comment: It's not clear to me that he needs an array formula.

Comment: Yeah an example would be the best. It looks like the lookup range and the lookup member are set to spill down. Probably not ideal.

Comment: updated with an image

Comment: well, an image is better than nothing, but just barely.  It looks like you are trying to get the video views that match a specific URL?  But I can't see the sheet names.  Is that two different sheets?  Or the same sheet and you are just trying to show the whole range? If it's two different sheets, then you aren't showing the ranges that are being referenced in your formula.  Are you really using Google Sheets?  Because that looks like Excel to me, and I don't think the K2:K reference is valid in Excel, although it works in Google sheets. A lot of issues that can't be answered from this pic.

Comment: Were you able to resolve your problem?

Comment: yes - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68853847/google-sheets-match-index-query

Answer (score 0):

It is always tough to write formulas without context. But it sounds like you are trying to use this in Sheet2, in the top cell of some column that is parallel to Column E in that sheet. If that is true, you can use this:

`=ArrayFormula({"Video Views";IF(E2:E="",,IFERROR(VLOOKUP(E2:E,{Sheet1!Z2:Z,Sheet1!K2:K},2,FALSE)))})`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to use arrayformula+index+match to get an array of the lookup values, and then using {} to append that to "Video Views", which I'm guessing is your column header, so you can get all the answers in one calculation.  Don't.  Just use index/match by itself, then copy it down.  It will be easier to troubleshoot, easier to maintain, easier to read, and probably perform much better.

I'm going to guess that you want to get the video views into Sheet1!L:L (the bottom half of your image), and you want to use the values from Sheet1!F:F to match against the links in column Z on Sheet2, and return the video views from Sheet2!K:K.

If that is the case, the try this formula in Sheet1!L2:

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!K:K, MATCH(Sheet1!F2, Sheet2!Z:Z, 0))
```

and then copy that down.

But I am really just guessing.