# Google Sheets Match/Index Query

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, indexing, vlookup, array-formulas

I need to match "column q" and "column f", then return "column p" value in "column l" based on that match.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10h7b-VfadXU6jzqB70CNIlnl2yXCMq1H6XVOrCqCLdc/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(F2:F, {Q2:Q, P2:P}, 2, 0)))
```

[image]